# Bootstrap 4 не растягивает блок на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы Bootstrap растягивал блоки на всю ширину экрана?
 Сразу скажу, что div с классом `container-fluid`, но по бокам все равно остается где-то 3% отступа, как это исправить?
 Надо, чтобы блоки растягивались на всю ширину экрана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `class="container-fluid m-0 p-0"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте к `container-fluid` классы `m-0` `p-0`, а к row класс `no-gutters`:

```css
span {
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container container-fluid m-0 p-0">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```